# SQL Query joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables as below:

1.Products

```
product_id, name
    1       Books A
    2       Books B
    3       Books C
    4       Books D
    5       Books E
```

2.liked_items

```
user_id, product_id
   1         4
   1         3
   1         1
```

I want to query (sql) to retrieve result as below.
Can I do in same single query?

```
product_id,  user_id
1              1
2              0
3              1
4              1
5              0
```

Hi, this first time i'm posting here. 
Hope anyone can help me. Thank you

Comment: It appears to be a homework question, you should follow: [How to ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). If not show some working of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Products.product_id,liked_items.product_id,liked_items.user_id 
FROM Products 
     LEFT JOIN liked_items 
     ON Products.product_id=liked_items.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
SELECT  a.product_ID,
        COALESCE(b.user_id,0) `user_id`
FROM    products a 
        LEFT JOIN liked_items b
            ON a.product_ID = b.product_ID
```

Sometimes `liked_items.user_id` can be possibly `NULL` so instead of displaying `NULL` in the result list, it can be changed using `COALESCE`. `COALESCE` is a function that can change `NULL` value into your *desired value*.

## [*Click For Demonstration*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e79c/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Products.product_id AS product_id,
  IFNULL(liked_items.user_id,0) AS user_id
FROM Products
  LEFT JOIN liked_items ON liked_items.product_id=Products.product_id
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using MS SQL Server you can use IsNull like so:

```
SELECT p.product_id, IsNull(li.user_id, 0)
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN liked_items li 
   ON (p.product_id = li.product_id);
```

If not, Joao or John's answer will do just fine.